# TeamCity + ReportGenerator

Tags: testing, teamcity, reportgenerator, coverlet

Good morning guys

I am using coverlet to run my tests in TeamCity. This works fine after I run the tests I would like to generate the report.

```
Write-Host "Installing report generator" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor White 

dotnet tool install --tool-path tools dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool

Write-Host "Finished installic report generator" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor White 

reportgenerator "-reports:$filesString" "-targetDir:$targetDir"
```

Above solution is working locally however in TeamCity I have following error:

> reportgenerator : The term 'reportgenerator' is not recognized as the
> name of  a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
> the spelling of  the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
> path is correct and try  again.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are installing ReportGenerator to the `tools` folder.

Executing it with `tools\reportgenerator` should work for you.

You may have a look at the "Readme" tab here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool/5.0.0

It shows 3 different installation options and the corresponding command to run ReportGenerator as a global tool

This is not specific to ReportGenerator. Every global tools has the same behavior.